# Converting an ArrayList to an array

Tags: java, collections, arraylist

I have the following problem... I want to read unknown number of strings from the input. So, I made an arraylist 'words' and added all the strings from the input. Then I wanted to convert this arraylist into simpler String array 'wordsarray'(String[])... As I did that I wanted to check if everything is ok (if words are saved in 'wordsarray') so I 
tried to print out the whole array... but it doesn't give me what I wanted... It seems like my code does not work. Where is the problem?
Thanks for your help

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    List<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();

    while(sc.hasNextLine()) {
         words.add(sc.nextLine());
    }

    String[] wordsarray = new String[words.size()];

    for(int i = 0; i < words.size(); i++) {
        wordsarray[i] = words.get(i);
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < words.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(wordsarray[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: What does it output?

Comment: nothing or two strings at best... nothing more than that...

Comment: Does it intermittently return two strings only? Or does a change you make cause it to return two strings?

Comment: Does the ArrayList Itself contain everything? Print out what it contains as well to check.

Comment: It seems like the second for loop never executes ... weird

Comment: That would only happen if `words.size()==0`. Try printing `words.size()`

Comment: i tried that... words.size() is not 0... it is of correct value

Comment: how do I put an end of file in eclipse's console? CTRL+D does not seem to work...

Comment: CTRL-Z is the EOF in windows, try that

Comment: ctrl+z doesn't work in eclipse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works fine for me:

```
import java.util.*;

public class a
{
  public static void main (String [] args) throws Exception
  {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    List<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();

    while(words.size () < 3 && sc.hasNextLine ()) {
        String s = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println ("Adding " + s);
        words.add(s);
    }

    String[] wordsarray = words.toArray(new String [] {});

    for(int i = 0; i < words.size(); i++) {
       System.out.println("Printing ..." + wordsarray[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

Output:

```
java a
1
Adding 1
2
Adding 2
3
Adding 3
Printing ...1
Printing ...2
Printing ...3
```

Comment: try to do it for unknown number of inputs

Comment: You have to have some sort of condition in this scenario where you stop taking any more inputs. In my case, I just added a total count of 3. You can look at Jack's response where it stops taking input if a blank character is passed. This way you can input as many text values as you want, and just pass blank character ("") to finish entering. Let me know if you need any more help with this.

Answer (score 4):

There is a precooked method to do what you are trying to do:

```
ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
String[] array = words.toArray(new String[words.size()]);
```

But your code seems correct, are you sure everything is fetched fine inside the `ArrayList`?

By your comment I guess that the problem is the fact that you don't place everything inside a loop. This code:

```
while(sc.hasNextLine()) {
  words.add(sc.nextLine());
}
```

works only once. If you keep inserting words and pressing enter you are already outside the loop because the `Scanner` already reached a point in which it didn't have any more lines to fetch.

You should do something like:

```
boolean finished = false;

while (!finished) {
  while(sc.hasNextLine()) {
      String line = sc.nextLine();
      if (line.equals(""))
        finished = true;
      else
        words.add(sc.nextLine());
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I printed out specific elements and they are ok